# Crown a list of two sublists with ErrorBar without losing list structure

Tags: expression-manipulation, map

I have a list with two sublists of numbers, e.g.

`Sigmaf = {{1,2,3},{3,4,5}};`

... and I would like to crown each number with `ErrorBar` to yield:

`{{ErrorBar[1], ErrorBar[2], ErrorBar[3]},{ErrorBar[3], ErrorBar[4], ErrorBar[5]}}`

I have tried:

`MapThread[ErrorBar[#] &, Flatten[Sigmaf]]`

... as well as:

`MapThread[ErrorBar[#] &, Sigmaf]`

... without success. Any tips?

Comment: Why use `ErrorBar` instead of `Around`? If you're using a more recent version of Mathematica, `Around` is the modern way to achieve this (and is better supported).

Comment: "Crown".......?

Answer (score 3):

**1.** `Map` `ErrorBar` at level `-1`:

```
Map[ErrorBar, Sigmaf, {-1}]
```

> ```
> {{ErrorBar[1], ErrorBar[2], ErrorBar[3]}, 
>  {ErrorBar[3], ErrorBar[4],  ErrorBar[5]}}
> ```

**2.** `ReplaceAll` replacing number `x` with `ErrorBar[x]`:

```
Sigmaf /. x_?NumericQ :> ErrorBar[x]
```

> ```
> {{ErrorBar[1], ErrorBar[2], ErrorBar[3]}, 
> {ErrorBar[3], ErrorBar[4], ErrorBar[5]}}
> ```

**3.** `Map` `ErrorBar` on `Flatten`ed input list and use  `` Internal`CopyListStructure ``:

```
Internal`CopyListStructure[Sigmaf, ErrorBar /@ Flatten[Sigmaf]]
```

> ```
> {{ErrorBar[1], ErrorBar[2], ErrorBar[3]}, 
> {ErrorBar[3], ErrorBar[4], ErrorBar[5]}}
> ```

Comment: The `{-1}` is equivalent to `{2}` for this particular case right? +1, as I wasn't aware of negative levels until today.

Comment: @flinty, thank you for the vote.  Yes, `{-1}` is the same as `{2}` for this case. `{-1}`  particularly convenient for sublists with different depths.